# How do I add multiple buttons to Tiny MCE in a single plugin?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, visual-editor

I'm using a custom plugin to add custom buttons to my visual editor. Right now, I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.trickspanda.com/2014/03/add-custom-button-wordpress-tinymce-editor/) and added a "code" button, but I'd also like to add a "cite" button that wraps the selected text in `<cite></cite>` tags. I'm sure I could just duplicate the plugin and make the minor changes, but that seems clunky and inefficient, and I'd much rather add both buttons via the same plugin.

I see that there's a related question about this [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/how-to-add-multiple-buttons-to-tinymce), but it's from a few years ago, and I'm using WordPress 3.9.1, which uses a new version of TinyMCE. Because of that, I'm not entirely sure how much of that answer is relevant, or how to apply it to TinyMCE 4.*.

Here's the PHP script that I use to add a "code" button:

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'code_button' );

function code_button() {
    add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", "code_add_button" );
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'code_register_button' );
}
function code_add_button( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['mycodebutton'] = $dir = plugins_url( 'shortcode.js', __FILE__ );
    return $plugin_array;
}
function code_register_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'codebutton' );
    return $buttons;
```

And the relevant JS file:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.code', {
        init : function(ed, url) {

            ed.addButton('codebutton', {
                title : 'Code',
                cmd : 'codebutton',
                icon: 'icon dashicons-editor-code'
            });

            ed.addCommand('codebutton', function() {
                var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
                var return_text = '';
                return_text = '<code>' + selected_text + '</code>';
                ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
            });
        },
        // ... Hidden code
    });
    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'mycodebutton', tinymce.plugins.code );
})();
```

What changes do I need to make to these files to add another custom button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this over on Stack Overflow, and got the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25148508/2110135) from user Howlin:

> There is a plugin that should help you, it's called [Visual Editor
>   Custom Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-editor-custom-buttons/).
>
> Once installed there is an option on the dashboard menu called Visual
>   Editor Custom Buttons,
>
> - There is an option called Add new
> - Call the new style something e.g. Cite.
> - Make sure the "Wrap Selection" option is ticked
> - In the "Before" box enter what you want to be wrapped before the content e.g. ""
> - In the "After" box enter what you want to be wrapped after the content e.g. ""
> - In the "Display in Editor" box below the above tick one or both of the options there.
> - If the Visual/Text are selected then choose the button icon/Quick label (optional)
> - Once all the above is done click on the blue "Publish" on the right hand side of the screen.
> - Open the page/post you want the new style on and highlight the text.
> - Click on the style you just created and it should be inserted.

This plugin allows me to easily do what I wanted without playing with code I don't understand. Works for me!